# Can I download NPM package binaries for an Intel architecture, on an ARM Mac?

Tags: npm

I have a script that is sending `node_modules` files to AWS using CloudFormation and SAM (infrastructure provisioning technologies).

The provisioned infrastructure is Intel x64, meaning any binaries in the node_modules files sent from my ARM machine are not runnable.

Can I force NPM to download Intel binaries?